# Why mainboards don't count power-on hours?

Tags: windows, motherboard, smart

As we know, each hard drive counts its power-on count and power-on hours. Why these interesting values aren't counted also by mainboards?

It would be nice to look at all those old computers I have at home a see how many operating hours they achieved.

Or do at least Windows count it?

I know that there probably is some third party software to do that, but I don't consider it reliable, because during the long life of a computer I usually change the operating system and whole disk a few times.

Answer (score 2):

Responding your main question:

Knowing for how long a motherboard was powered might be interesting to you, but it's ultimately a meaningless statistic.

However, the power-on hours of a hard drive are designed to estimate the mechanical wear and ultimately how likely it is that the hard drive will begin to fail shortly.

Also, your premise that *all* hard drives store this information is wrong. There are Hard drives that don't support [S.M.A.R.T.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) at all, and even if they do, they don't *have to* count power-on hours.

Answer (score 1):

> As we know, each hard drive counts its power-on count and power-on
>   hours. Why these interesting values aren't counted also by mainboards?

Where would this information be stored exactly?  The information you are asking about is stored in a cache within the physical hardware of the HDD.  This information follows a semi-standard called `S.M.A.R.T` it is useful dianostic information.

> It would be nice to look at all those old computers I have at home a
>   see how many operating hours they achieved.

Unless the storage devices in question supported S.M.A.R.T this is not possible.

> Or do at least Windows count it?

Most operating systems can only keep track of how long they were ran without a restart.  You can figure out the lifetime of the system by finding the oldest file on the storage device.

> I know that there probably is some third party software to do that,
>   but I don't consider it reliable, because during the long life of a
>   computer I usually change the operating system and whole disk a few
>   times.

So even if the operating system tracked this information, it would be lost, because you would have wiped the information.

Comment: *"Where would this information be stored exactly?"* - How about the same memory chip where the clock/calender and BIOS configuration data are stored?